# UI for manage git submodules

Tags: git, ubuntu, debian, gitlab

my question is, if is posible manage git submodules without console commands, with some UI?, gitlab do this? or exists another tool for this?
The SO is ubuntu 16.04 or Debian
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many git gui tools that also support submodules. [GitKraken](http://gitkraken.com/), for example, which runs on Windows, Mac and Linux. You should be aware, however, that you always have most control when you use the command line.

Comment: thanks, i will try it.. but i have another question, GitKraken also manage git groups for some projects? manage permissions for some people in a project? Thanks again.

Comment: No. GitKraken only manages your repository and the data in it. Managing permissions for project collaborators is a completely different process; it's done server-side wherever the project is hosted. GitHub, GitLab and Bitbucket would be well known examples here.

Comment: No problem! If I answered your question, however, it would be nice if you [mark the answer as correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow).